# several packages available from epel, but not git?

Tags: git, fedora, rhel, epel

I've just installed the epels, and I've found that a lot of git-related projects are available, but git itself is not!

```
GitPython.noarch                                                                                   0.3.2-0.6.RC1.el6                                                                                           epel
git-annex.x86_64                                                                                   3.20120522-2.1.el6                                                                                          epel
git-bugzilla.noarch                                                                                0-0.9.20091211git.el6                                                                                       epel
git-cal.noarch                                                                                     0.9.1-3.el6                                                                                                 epel
git-ftp.noarch                                                                                     0.84-1.el6                                                                                                  epel
git-review.noarch                                                                                  1.17-2.el6                                                                                                  epel
git2cl.noarch                                                                                      2.0-0.1.git8373c9f.el6                                                                                      epel
gitflow.noarch                                                                                     0.4.2.20120723git53e9c76-4.el6                                                                              epel
gitolite.noarch                                                                                    2.3.1-1.el6                                                                                                 epel
gitolite3.noarch                                                                                   1:3.6-1.el6                                                                                                 epel
gitosis.noarch                                                                                     0.2-9.20080825git.el6                                                                                       epel
gitso.noarch                                                                                       0.6-10.el6                                                                                                  epel
gitstats.noarch                                                                                    0-0.4.20130723gita923085.el6                                                                                epel
gitweb-caching.noarch                                                                              1.6.5.2-8.b1ab8b5.el6    

                                                                               epel
```

Why is git not in the EPEL repositories, and what is the simplest way to get it installed, idiomatically, on a RHEL or Fedora machine?

Answer (score 0):

In RHEL, git is provided in the `production-rhel-x86_64-workstation-major.minor` (e.g., for RHEL 6.5, use `production-rhel-x86_64-workstation-6.5`).

In Fedora it's provided by the `fedora` and by the `updates` repos.

Comment: ah, so its excluded from epel for that reason?

Comment: I believe it's just considered redundant to have in epel, as the "basic" repos already provide it.